# Fix or alternative to ADL when one of the functions is actually a function object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup, customization-point, tag-dispatching

In the following code, the standalone component in the namespace `S` has its own definitions of `Big` and `Small` types, together with a `split` function to split one `Big` into a collection of the `Small`s.

`S` also provides another function, `work`, which makes use of `split`, and is meant to be used by `S` itself and also by other dependent components, e.g. the one in the namespace `D`, which are assumed to provide their own definitions of `Big` and `Small` and their own definition of `split`, which will be identified via ADL.¹

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace S /* standalone */ {
    struct Big{};
    struct Small{};
    std::vector<Small> split(Big b) {
        std::cout << "S" << std::endl;
        return {/* use b to make output */};
    }
    template<typename BigT>
    void work(BigT/* acutally this is a template class with `BigT` as a template paramter*/ x) {
        split(x); // correspondingly `split` is not applied on `x` but on the `BigT` which is part of it
        // a lot of complex stuff
    }
}

namespace D /* dependent on standalone */ {
    struct Big{};
    struct Small{};
    std::vector<Small> split(Big b) {
        std::cout << "D" << std::endl;
        return {/* use b to make output */};
    }
}
int main() {
    S::Big line1{};
    D::Big line2{};
    S::work(line1); // uses S::split
    S::work(line2); // uses D::split
}
```

Well, in reality `S::split` is a function object, not a function²,

```cpp
namespace S {
    struct Split {
        std::vector<Small> operator()(Big) const {
            std::cout << "S" << std::endl;
            return {};
        }
    } split;
}
```

so ADL doesn't work.

Any suggestion on how to address these needs?

From the comments emerges that maybe Niebloids and/or `tag_invoke` represent an answer to my question. And I'd really like to understand more about these concepts.

For now, my understanding of Niebloids (and I'm reading [this blog from Eric Niebler](http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/)) is that they are function objects that (when they're in scope) prevent ADL, thus "focusing" all function calls directed to unqualified free functions with the same name as the niebloid; their `operator()`, however, relies on ADL to forward the call to the appropriate *free* function. Therefore it looks like the contrast in my example code between `S::split` being a function object and `D::split` being a free function cannot be addressed by niebloids, unless I make `S::split` a free function (in which case ADL would suffice in my simple scenario).

---

¹ Originally `work` was defined in both `S` and `D`, and the code above is my attempted refactoring, during which I run into the described issue.

² The reason for this is that `S::split` is used in several contexts in `S`, it has a few overloads of `operator()`, and most importantly, it's often passed around as an object, which is very handy.

Comment: Can you add an overload of `work` in `S` that accepts a function object that will be used instead of the split object from `S`?

Comment: @NathanOliver, at first I'd say no, because all the refactoring I'm doing is to have `work` in one place only, from where it can be used by other components, provided they customize the behavior of `work` by providing their own `split` for their own `Big`/`Small`. However, probably you are referring to a `D::work` which would only call at `S::work` to do the job?

Comment: No, I mean have a `work` in `S` like `template<typename BigT, typename Splitter> void work(BigT x, Splitter s)`and then you would have your original `work` function call this one with `work(x, S::split);`.  Then all "derived" components would also call the new template and pass their own splitter to `work`.  Makes a little more work at the call site but keeps everything in `S`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24c0bd68605e5553)?

Comment: You also might be interested by `tag_invoke`.

Comment: @Jarod42, as regards the first comment, I'd avoid modifying the `Big` classes. It looks a lot like a convoluted workaround. As regards the second, do you refer to niebloids?

Comment: Not familiar with `tag_invoke`, I have just read some [stuff](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1895r0.pdf) recently, but I think yes.